# how to paste text to left of original text like ultraedit column mode

Tags: sublimetext2

I have below original text:

```
a:1
b:2
c:3
d:4
```

I want to paste below content into right side of original text area

```
a:5
b:7
e:10
```

Result should be:

```
a:1   a:5
b:2   b:7
c:3   e:10
d:4
```

it is easy to finish it by ultraedit columnn mode. but how to do in sublime quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [column selection](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html).

Go to the end of first line, and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> on Windows and Linux) as many times as you need. Then add the number of spaces that you need, and paste your text.

Comment: By your method, i must paste it one by one three times.
how to get correct result by copy&paste once

Comment: If you do what I wrote, you can paste once.

You have three line to paste, so you press ctrl+shift+down three times, then you can insert spaces and paste.

Comment: Got it. already solve it.
Before, i copy four line(not three), the 4th line is blank line, so that show unexpected result.
By the way, shortcut should be ctrl+alt+down.

Comment: Sorry, ctrl-shift-down is on MacOS. Windows and Linux use ctrl-alt-down. I updated the text.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sublime Text 2 trick shift+ctrl+L split lines]
Sublime Text 2 trick shift+ctrl+L split lines